# How to prevent converting photoshop shape into mask in Flash?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-flash

By importing a simple solid vector shape from Photoshop into Flash it convert into a shape and a mask. It makes editing very difficult. Is is possible to change this behavior?

Photoshop:

[image]

Flash:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried multiple ways to recreate what you are experiencing without any luck. But a simple and easy solution is to just right-click on the layer that is a mask and then click on "mask". It will remove the check mark and the layer will become a normal shape again.